# .NET Possibilities for a Dashboard Application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, components, dashboard

My situation is as follows:

I am creating a dashboard framework, in which I want to develop multiple applications. Each application should have its own View (HTML & JS), Model (currently using EF6) and MVC Controllers. Preferably all contained in one folder.

A dashboard is able to have the same application multiple time on its page, but with different settings. These settings are stored in a DB which allocates a UID to the instance of such an application. So for example: lets say I have a HTMLContainer application. This application should replace its inner html based on a given setting.
The HTML & JS would look something like this:

```js
$('#htmlContainer').innerHTML = "This value would be retrieved from a .NET server/controller based on a certain UID which should be given to this 'component' when instantiated.";
```

```html
<div id="htmlContainer">This should be replaced based on the settings retrieved</div>
```

Since we want to have a dashboard, we need it to be possible to have the same HTMLContainer on the same page, multiple times.

This introduces two challenges:

- We should be able to make the id="htmlContainer" unique by adding some kind of UID to it. So the ID would become 'htmlContainer-1384' for example. This could be done by changing something in the renderer when for example choosing for ASP.NET MVC.
- The next challenge is one I am struggling with the most. Since the ID of the HTML would change, the JS attached to the HTML wouldn't work anymore. We would need a way to remain the scope of the JS for that HTMLContainer application. This is where I get stuck at the moment.

I haven't found an ASP.NET Framework which supports this kind of behaviour, without customizing a lot of core functionality of that framework.

I was really wondering if anyone could help me out and maybe has experience with creating dashboards and dashboard applications using an ASP.NET framework. The reason I specifically want an ASP.NET framework, is because a lot of external libraries I am currently using are in .NET.

Let me know if I need to add more information to make my situation clear.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you committed to building your own framework from scratch? I would suggest using a matured front end framework such as Angular, and pull whatever data you need to render the content from .Net Api controllers.

Comment: Nice suggestion. We currently tried to make a Angular 2 front end with a ASP.NET Web API 2 back end. Unfortunately this resulted in having the back end separated from the front end. Usually this is a good thing, but we wanted to maintain all the necessary files for one component/application within one folder. This meant this solution wouldn't be exactly what we wanted. Also, this solution would require a certain learning curve for our developers to learn Angular 2 and typescript. That's why we are trying to explore different possible solutions.

Comment: Use HTML classes, i.e. `.htmlContainer`, not `#htmlContainer-1384`. Ids must be unique, but the whole point of HTML classes is to apply style or behavior to a group of similar things. Alternatively, if you insist on ids, you can always use the attribute starts with selector: `[id^=htmlContainer]`, which would catch anything that has id that starts with `htmlContainer`, i.e. `#htmlContainer-1234` and `#htmlContainer-5678`.

Comment: FWIW, though, the stuff I mentioned in the previous comment is like HTML 101. If you don't know *that*, creating an entire dashboard framework from the ground up is likely far too ambitious.

Comment: Using classes is not an option. I'll give another example:
Let's say you have two applications with the same base code. The application has a label-element with a number in it (0 from the start for example) and a button. When you click the button, the number within the label element should increase by one. Let's say you have two of those applications on your page. Same base code, same application. I now want to prevent that when I click the button on one instance, that it would affect the other. That's why I need a UID to distinguish those instances. Therefore classes are not really an option

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "two of those applications on your page." That doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Object Orient Javascript practices. You will have only one application with multiple instances of the same class.

Create a class that keeps track of the number of instances of itself, and use that instance ID to seed your UIDs for each element that requires it.

It would look something like this:

```
// private static
var nextId = 0;

// constructor
function MyComponent(element) {
    if (!(this instanceof MyComponent)) return new MyComponent();

    // private        
    var id = nextId++; //component instance ID
    var divId = 'div-id-' + id;
    var spanId = 'span-id-' + id;

    function renderUniqueComponent(sender, args){
        var el = document.getElementById(element);
        var data = getDataFromServer();

        el.innerHTML += '<div id=' + divId + '>'
                            + '<span id=' + spanId + '>'
                                + data
                            + '</span>'
                      + '</div>';
    }

    function getDataFromServer(){
       //make an Ajax call to your API
    }

};
```

This will render the same component with unique Id's for each element, and produce unique content retrieved from your api.

You should load this file only once per page, and call it's constructor for each instance of the component you need, passing in the element reference for the target element in which to render the new component.